# Serialize model instances only

Tags: jena

I have an ontology that I load into Jena using a ModelFactory and a TurtleReader. Works great.

I then use that mode to create individuals via the createIndividuals() method. I can add those back to the original model and serialize it using an RDFDataMgr and I get good output containing the original ontology along with the new individuals.

However, what I would really like to be able to do is to just get the correctly serialized individuals (complete with required @prefix statements) NOT the entire original ontology along with the individuals.

Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the new instances in a separate model? You can copy the prefixes from the original model into the new one. Also - see the ModelFactory.crateUnion and it's javadoc.

Comment: No that doesn't work as I need the original classes to create individuals, which are automatically added to the ontology (model) that was used to create them.